# Did Charles Xavier know about Peter Quill?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

Peter Quill seems to have been born in 1981, and then abducted from Earth in 1988.  There were therefore 7 years in which the child of a Celestial was on Earth.

**Is there any indication given of whether or not Charles Xavier sensed Peter's existence?**

I am not sure when Cerebro was created.

Of course, the source can be anywhere in the comics. Obviously, the movie universes are different, but many characters coexist in the comics despite being segregated in the movies.

Comment: Um, these are two different movie universes. Charles Xavier is a mutant, and thus only in Fox’s *X-Men* movies. Peter Quill is in Disney’s MCU.

Comment: @Adamant - recent productions, particularly Deadpool, A:Age of Ultron, and CA:Civil War have started to break down the walls between the Fox, Disney, and Sony movie universes...

Comment: @HorusKol - …not really? The truth is, the X-Men timeline (any of them) is basically inconsistent with the MCU timeline. Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver are dual licensed (not the same characters), Deadpool is being meta (not crossing over), and Spiderman wasn’t part of the X-Men universe either (plus, this is a new Spider-Man).

Comment: @Adamant - the X-Men timeline is inconsistent with itself... Deadpool - the final fight is located on one of the SHIELD helicarriers brought down at the end of CA:Winter Soldier - personally, I find most of the "barriers" between the different universes are artificial (especially with all the timeline/universe messing around in the comic books) and are mostly done for commercial reasons - all the Marvel (comic) movies sit happily together in my collection regardless of who owns the rights.

Comment: @HorusKol - That’s why the X-Men timeline has time travel. ;) The arrangement of movies on your shelf may not depend on rights holders, but it’s not about rights holders. It’s about whether X-Men makes any sense as the same story as the MCU (it doesn’t). As for Deadpool, it makes a lot of jokes that we really shouldn’t take too seriously. It’s meta. It’s what Deadpool does. If you really care, though, technically the MCU, comics, and all the Marvel licensed properties are different universes in a multiverse..but that still doesn’t put Charles Xavier on Earth-199999 at any point in the timeline

Comment: @Adamant - so far...

Comment: I mean, one might as well as how Spider-Man could go back to high school after he was in college in *Spider-Man* 3. They’re not the same story, and they’re not supposed to be. And as mentioned previously, in the comics (where Xavier and Peter do coexist), Peter is not the child of a Celestial....

Comment: Cerebro couldn't detect Peter Quill as he doesn't have X-gene. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/42966/931

Comment: @IAMGROOT Peter had Celestial genes. And this link that you added to one of my other questions indicates that the X gene is a derivative of the Celestial genes http://marvel.com/universe/Celestials#axzz4hmRzzQNH

Comment: So what? A machine can detect derivative. It doesn't mean it would also be able to detect original. A device which can detect diesel won't be able to detect crude petroleum, for example.

Comment: “Peter Quill seems to have been born in 1981, and then abducted from Earth in 1988. There were therefore 7 years in which the child of a Celestial was on Earth... Of course, the source can be anywhere in the comics” — I believe those story points (Quill being abducted, and being the child of a Celestial) are only seen in the MCU *Guardians of the Galaxy* movie, so the comics aren’t really relevant.

Answer (score 14):

No. Ego is only Peter Quill's father in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Charles Xavier does not exist in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, as X-Men movie rights are not controlled by Marvel Studios at the moment (instead, Fox).

See [What makes a movie part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127686/what-makes-a-movie-part-of-the-marvel-cinematic-universe) for more information.

As Adamant mentioned, Peter Quill's backstory in the comics is quite a bit different. He is the son of J'son (King/Emperor of Spartoi) who is member of a human-like alien species without any clear superpowers.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the scope could include the comics.

Comment: @CodeMed- But Peter Quill’s father is J’son in the comics, who is not a Celestial. He’s only a Celestial in the movie universe, where it doesn’t make any sense to ask about Xavier. Also, the [tag:guardians-of-the-galaxy-2] tag is for the MCU movie, so for a question about comic books it wouldn’t be appropriate.

Comment: Also this question was tagged with [marvel-cinematic-universe] when I answered.